# How to spawn a proccess and comunicate with it

Tags: c#, node.js, sockets

I am building an API with NodeJs that is used to run `.exe` files on the server side. To spawn the proccess of the `.exe` file, I am simply using the `child_process` module, like:

```
let p = spawn('test.exe', []);
```

And then I can use the `stdout` "listener" to get the messages written in the standard output of `test.exe` like:

```
p.stdout.on('data', (data) => console.log(data.toString()));
```

My `test.exe` in the example is written in C# and only sleeps and write stuff on the `stdout`.

I would like to know if there's a way to communicate these two process other than the `stdout`. I have a feeling it would be something about sockets, but I've never worked with it before. Can someone point me in some direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Http, Rest, IPC, named pipes, message queuing, protobuf, ... Pick one

Comment: I like pointing people to the msdn socket examples.

Comment: Hi guys. Thanks for the answer. Well, I would like to pick the simplest one. It is really only to communicate through messages (strings). That's why the `stdout` is working as it is now... Which one would you recomend?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be http (see node/express).
But the 'best' solution would depend on your needs.  It's worth while to look into named pipes and IPC

Comment: Ok, another stupid question. When you say a way to my process to comunicate with the server is `http`, you are basically saing that my process should make an http request to the local server? If so, I was expecting something more on process level (since both my server and the application will be sharing the SO). Will check about the named pipes

Comment: Named Pipes and/or IPCs is the way to go.. It's a little more involved but worth the journey.. http is a good solution if you needed done in 10 minutes.